# collapse in hide or show do it from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I write some control unit that switch couple of containers by using "collapse" class from bootstrap like list with anchors that has special for my hidden containers "href" attribute, here is example of two list elements that can describe behaviour:

```
<div id="my_list">
  <ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a onclick="return false" data-parent="#switch_tables" href="#collapse1">One</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a onclick="return false" data-parent="#switch_tables" href="#collapse2">Two</a>
 </li>
</div>
```

Then in html code i use some container:

```
<div id="switch_tables" class="panel">
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse in"> SOME IN HERE </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse"> SOMETHING ELSE</div>
</div>
```

So when i use this stuff and first elemet of list is active the first container is shown too because i add "in" class after "collapse" class. When I switch to the other list element, then first container should dissappear and the second one should be shown. Of course I has more list links and more hidden containers than just 2 but it's just an example. The thing that I want to do is to prevent default behaviour and to forbid active elemet to hide by clicking on it.

So I switch the "active" list element by clicking on list items and also show or hide exact container that has same id that the list has, so the containers is linked with list items, this thing is done by js code:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        var to_toggle = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        $(to_toggle+':not(".in")').collapse('show');
    });
});
```

And now I see when I switch between list items, the containers appear and hide correctly.

When I click on second link, I see how first container is hiding and the second one is appear, and vice versa.

Idea is that if there is open containers, the ones that has "collapse in" class should be closed by js, but how to forbid closing an active container?

For example I click on second link in list, my first container is hiding, second one is appear, I click on second link again and second container dissappear so I dont see anything on screen. but the list item is active.

So the question is how to modify js so only one container can have "collapse in" class at a time, and nothing can remove it until the user will switch it to other container so class "in" will move to other container that is coming from anchor attribute "href" and can't be removed in this place?

Answer (score 0):

So I solve my problem by point from [@Zigri2612](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5150781/zigri2612) but use little different approach:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        var to_toggle = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#switch_tables").find('div').each(function(){
            if ( ('#'+$(this).attr("id")) != to_toggle )
                $(this).filter('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        });

        $(to_toggle+':not(".in")').collapse('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: My approach works and don't allow to hide active container, Zigri2612 forget to use "to_toggle" variable.

Comment: i am just suggesting idea,but you are not appreciated. i have posted better sol. after adapting in you solution....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap , so you can use bootstrap collapse feature for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Collapse</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Collapse <small>Bootstrap Visual Test</small></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
     Collapse one content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
         Collapse two content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- JavaScript Includes -->
<script src="../vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../transition.js"></script>
<script src="../../collapse.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap in context of only collapse functionality, i.e. it's animation of expand/collapse. so I don't want use buttons or so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for **collapse** `hide` and `show`. here the plus and minus `icons` are changing. you can alter it for your need.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        // Add minus icon for collapse element which is open by default
        $(".collapse.show").each(function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").addClass("fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus");
        });
        
        // Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        });
    });
```

```css
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .accordion .fa{
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>


<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> What is HTML?</button>                                  
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the standard markup language for describing the structure of web pages. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> What is Bootstrap?</button>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> What is CSS?</button>                     
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```